# How to refer to United States of America?

Tags: grammar

My sentence is:

> ATC experienced rapid growth between 1880 to 1911. In 1890, their five main competitors joined their consortium and by 1910, the American Tobacco Company had absorbed 250 companies, producing 80% of the tobacco products **in the United States of America** and had grown its equity from $25 million to $316 million.

I am conflicted on how to refer to USA (Bold part)

Is it:

**in the United States of America**

or

**in United States of America**

Also, sneaky second question if you guys don't mind :)

Do you think my sentence is too long?

Comment: say: **in the US**

Comment: Also "between 1880 and 1911" or "from 1880 to 1911".

Comment: In contexts like this, some countries (like the Netherlands) always get a "the" put in front of their name. Leave the "the" in there. And the answer to your "sneaky" question is subjective, but I'd say, "Yes."